# Display an expanded drill down report by default initially but should collapse based on the parameters selected in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2012

I would like to create a report that is expanded by default when first run.
For eg : I am using 3 fields in the dataset- Country,State,City
The first group would be for Country, the second group for State and the details group for City. All the groups would be of a tablix and created in a stepped style report as I want to create a drill down report with the toggle.

The problem is - I have 3 parameters - Summary,Intermediate,Detailed. When the user selects the Summary parameter, only the Country field is displayed with the toggle which when clicked, expands the State column and the toggle in the State column when clicked expands the City column, and can be collapsed also by clicking on the toggle.

When the user selects the Intermediate parameter, only the Country column and the expanded State column should be displayed when the report is initially run, and the toggle on the State column should take me to the City column and can be collapsed also by clicking on the toggle.

Similarly, when the user selects the Detailed parameter, all of the three columns should be displayed in the expanded state when the report is initially run and can be collapsed also by clicking on the toggle.

How can I achieve this?? I have tried a number of ways but no luck.

Please help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is called **Cascading Parameters**. What you want to do is use separate datasets for each parameter. Use the **Country** parameter in your dataset for the **State** and then use the **State** parameter in your **City** dataset.

```
SELECT DISTINCT State
FROM yourTable
WHERE Country = @Country
```

For more info, check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create three sets of each column (S_Country, S_State, S_City, then I_Counrty, and so on...).  Your visibility of the toggle items and unhidden items will be controlled by your parameter.  Here's what the Summary Countries Column visibility fx would be:

```
    =iif(Parameters!Format.Label = "Summary", False, True)
```

Set the Summary Country as the toggle item for the other two.  For the Intermediates, The Country and State visibility would be based on a similar formula as above, and the City hidden and toggled on the Intermediate Country.  All three Detail columns' visibility is controlled by the Parameter.

You might want to do a little research on Parameter Values and Labels.  It would be better to assign the words "Summary", "Intermediate", and "Detail" as Labels in the parameter, and use "1", "2", "3" for values.  That simplifies code to read:

```
=iif(Parameters!Format.value = 1, False, True)
```

It just takes a bit of creativity to get things like this to work in SSRS.